# Should "-->" have canonical questions in different languages?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I know this question has many duplicates:

[What is the "-->" operator in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642028/what-is-the-operator-in-c?rq=1)

However, some of them are in different languages,eg:

Java: [What does --> means in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29429605/what-does-means-in-java?noredirect=1&lq=1)

JavaScript: [How does the minus minus less than "-->" operator work in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39163582/how-does-the-minus-minus-less-than-operator-work-in-javascript?noredirect=1&lq=1)

c (<--) : [Why isn't there a "<--" operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22918048/why-isnt-there-a-operator)

to be honest, although I believe those duplicate can answer the questions, yet their language is different, which may have different outputs, rules  or additional explanation for "-->" (and even link to different offical docs), which is not quite make senses to mix them together.

If I see similar questions but in different languages later, should I mark it as duplicate of those c++ one? Or is it better to pick one with same language?

Comment: Interestingly the arrow operator not only apply for those mentioned languages, such as C#, Perl, PHP & Python also count. The limitation to implement such questions is even a canonical question can only hold a max of 5 tags, while it may require more than 5 tags to mention every languages using same operator token.

Comment: We can add tag in title to fix that!

Comment: @Tom, More bad ideas? It was just some sarcasm. But how could you have know without Emoji in comment! We really need emoji in comment!

Comment: @DragandDrop Ok, let's hope it really was just sarcasm ... ;P.

Comment: @Tom, Just sarcasm, The clue was that the linked Questions titles already contains tag . `[question title] in [tag]` is [not valid](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130208/334950).

Comment: @DragandDrop ok :).

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto where does that operator exist in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not likely that questions about an operator that's spelled the same in four different languages are going to boil down to the same root. They'll have different semantics and thus important distinctions from each other. Having an individual question for each language is ideal here.

(And, yes, putting the language in the title is okay, *as long as it's required* to distinguish it from others. Just do it as naturally as possible: particularly, without the square brackets.)

If you had a case where the underlying cause *was* the same -- the behavior of IEEE 754 floating point numbers, for example, or Unicode encoding -- then it could be justified to link the questions together by closing as duplicate. As long as there were no language-specific bits that were germane to the question.